# Minimizar el tamaño de un texto en una tabla HTML

Tags: html, css, html-tabla

Como estoy haciendo una pagina de una biblioteca las sipnosis son muy largas, y ocupan mucho espacio en la tabla, me gustaría que solo se mostraran unos cuantos renglones y luego aparecieran los "..." para que al darle click se muestre la información completa, he intentado de todas las formas y no lo logro.

Esta es mi tabla:

```
<div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-outline-light rounded-3 col-md-9">
        <h1 style="color: white;"><center>Lista de Libros</center></h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control me-2 light-table-filter" data-table="table_id" type="text" 
            placeholder="Buscar información">
            <hr>
        </form>
        </div>
            <?php
                $qry="SELECT * FROM libros";
                $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
            ?>
            <table class="table table-light table_id">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table table-danger">
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Autor</th>
                        <th scope="col">Publicación</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sinopsis</th>
                        <th scope="col">Portada</th>
                        <th scope="col">Disponibilidad</th>
                        <th scope="col" colspan="2"><center>Acciones</center></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row"><?php echo $registro['nombre']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="row"><?php echo $registro['autor']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="row"><?php echo $registro['publicacion']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="row" class="sinopsis"><span><?php echo $registro['sinopsis']; ?></span></td>
                        <td scope="row"><?php echo $registro['portada']; ?></td>
                        <td scope="row"><?php 
                                if($registro['disponibilidad'] ){
                                    echo "Disponible";
                                }else{
                                    echo "Ocupado/Reparación";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="../modulos/editar_libros.php?id=<?php echo $registro['id']; ?>" ><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></a></button>
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><a href="?id=<?php echo $registro['id']; ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" style="color: #ffffff;"></i></a></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                   <?php   }  ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Así es como se ve:
[image: Tabla]

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar [-webkit-line-clamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp) para indicar el número de líneas a mostrar, luego solo es agregar un evento que al hacer click añada o saque la clase que contiene dicha regla

Para usar `-webkit-line-clamp` es necesario agregar:

```
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => 
  document.querySelectorAll(".preview")
   .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", () =>
    el.classList.toggle('preview')
)));
```

```css
.preview{
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td class="preview">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```